# How to live with the frustration?

Tags: discussion, down-votes, accepted-answer

I face two sources of frustration on SE.

1. Anonymous, unexplained downvotes. They aren't fun and from my experience commenting to ask for an explanation just adds to the frustration as you never get a reply.
2. Accepted answers that you are convinced are wrong, though they keep getting upvotes. Claiming that they are wrong also has no effect as your post goes unnoticed or is not believed, an accepted answer often masking others.

*I am not claiming that I am always right to think an answer wrong - I may error too with significant probability. I am just saying that this is an uncomfortable situation.*

Have you found a way to cope with that? I am not looking for a way to counteract these situations, rather to accept misfortune :)

Update:
I forgot a third source of frustration: after you have carefully crafted a solution, with love, the OP never coming back.

Comment: If you're frustrated by SE, then maybe the SE model isn't for you. Nobody says it has to be.  Try going outside.

Comment: @Won't Just because a person gets frustrated with something doesn't mean they should quit. Most people get frustrated with life at points in their life. You obviously wouldn't recommend them just quitting life? The OP had a very good question that s/he accepts this is the reality and just wants to know how s/he could cope with this imperfect reality.

Comment: +1 Upvote! @Yves Daoust, this is the reality

Comment: @Roombatron5000 Can you point out where I said "quit?" I said "maybe" it isn't for everyone. Any other conclusions you would like to jump to that I can dissuade you of?

Comment: +1 wrong accepted and upvoted answers make the whole SE unreliable, untrusted resource

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Have you found a way to cope with that? I am not looking for a way to counteract these situations, rather to accept misfortune :)

When you receive a downvote you think wasn't deserved and you start getting frustrated about it try this:

1. Remove your hands from your technological device.
2. Make sure you are sitting comfortably.
3. For about 1-2 minutes, take long deep breaths.

This should already relieve much of the frustration your feeling. If you still have any tension left, then try this:

4. Think about some bad stories you heard/read about on the news.
5. Put your downvote frustration situation into perspective with these bad stories.
6. Feel good once you realize that the downvote(s) given to you aren't a big deal at all.
7. Laugh about the fact that you got upset over it in the first place.

Comment: Your recommendation would work for downvoter :) Especially the 1st three steps, so I favourited this post for future reference.

Answer (score 17):

> anonymous, unexplained downvotes

Yeah, they happen. To all of us. Learn to live with them - shrug them off and move on. Remember - the downvote costs you 2 rep, much less than an upvote, so as long as you have more upvotes than downvotes, you are in the black.

> accepted answers that you are convinced are wrong

If you are convinced, downvote and post a comment on the answer, explaining why it is wrong. Accept that the answer OP may never respond - but if they do, perhaps they will show you why they are not wrong.