# To show downvoter's name

Tags: feature-request, down-votes

I suggest to show downvoter's name so that we'll be able to decrease the number of unfair downvotes resulted by abusing his rights in doing so.

Comment: related: http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/254257/244519

Comment: There can be tons of related but the issue remains

Comment: Not sure what elections have got to do with anything (also, given the numbers involved - it his highly unlikely to have been any of the candidates). No idea why you'd even bring that up.

Comment: And really leaving comments like [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18180959/removing-a-document-by-passing-its-id-using-form-tag#comment47853155_18180959) only attracts downvotes...

Comment: You got a down vote, so what? I've had perfectly good questions down voted, you just have to live with it. Consider it part of the price of being active on the site. As for *"the issue remains"* - it's only an issue for those who want to make it an issue. Ignore it and move on.

Comment: @slugster, first of all let me thank for not being anonymous. Secondly, what do you benefit from downvoting perfectly good questions? Self-satisfaction?

Comment: The site has always operated with the policy that you do not have to justify or supply any reason for up votes or down votes. In general the system works pretty well, although not everyone is happy all the time. As for why people do it - some people just be hatin'. They may not have understood your question, or may not have liked your approach, or they may have been having a crappy day. We will never know. Showing names will just lead to conflict and retribution.

Comment: @slugster, yeah I understand there's always some sort of unfairness the same way we have in real world ;)

Comment: -1 For not considering the implications of this. What would you have done if they had left their names? Ranted at them?

Comment: @Tim are we still discussing this post or it's finished?

Comment: @Tim remove your comment from my SO, as people feeling power in SO enjoying doing down votes there

Comment: Powerful moderators, please remove this post.

Comment: @oscar I'm explaining my down vote. Would you rather I didn't explain it? To get a mod to remove it, either flag the comment or the post and select the other reason.

Comment: @oscar what discussion? Your post is about wanting people to say they down voted, yes? So that is what I did. What is the problem?

Comment: @Tim just noticed your comment has been removed from my post in SO, so I'm finished here. Have a nice day.

Comment: @oscar oh, that one. I thought it was sensible to give a notice to others that there was a meta discussion about it...

Comment: @Tim, actually that your comment in SO gave another effect - as James mentioned, people started down voting in SO just because of my post in Meta :)

Comment: @oscar My apologies, I didn't think of that.

Comment: @Tim, it's ok now. ;)

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Voting is deliberately anonymous, both up and down. If someone wants to share their name with you or the reasons for their vote, they'll do so.

If we opened up the system to letting everyone see who cast every vote, not only would that feel a bit too social-network-y for my taste, but it would also severely compromise the integrity of said votes.

Maybe I don't want to vote something down, because I fear the user will vote me down in response. Maybe I don't want to be known as that one guy who downvotes Jon Skeet. Maybe I just don't want to be seen as a "negative influence" on the community.

[Downvoting is important](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/03/the-value-of-downvoting-or-how-hacker-news-gets-it-wrong/), and as long as it's generally warranted, we don't want to try and talk anyone out of doing it.

We don't want anyone feeling pressured into voting one way or another, because one of the main reasons the Stack Exchange model works so much better than classic forums is that people can trust content they see ranked high up.

And even on top of that, we already have enough cases of people overreacting to a single downvote. Giving them a target human being to overreact *at* would just make the site that much less enjoyable for everyone.

The only time when it's appropriate to call a person out on the votes they've cast is when they're abusing the system. And even that is held private under normal circumstances.

Comment: Thanks for reply. But that specific post I brought in my post I think was unfairly downvoted. Of course, just one mouse click is very easy than explaining the reason.

Comment: @Oscar Lots of people think their posts have been unfairly downvoted. It's an icky feeling, but that's no reason to go and change the whole system for the worse. Just as someone randomly came across it and downvoted it, perhaps someone else will later randomly upvote it. That's how the system works.

Comment: If there would be the feature that force downvoters to explain the reason of downvoting, maybe who wouldn't downvote.

Comment: @oscar - and that would reduce the overall quality of posts all over the site. I think that's a bad trade-off. If less people downvote (which will happen if they are forced to leave feedback), there will be more bad posts staying around.

Comment: Thanks guys for replies. Just wanted to share with my thoughts.

Comment: @Oscar and thank you for that! It's important to think about these kinds of things, and work to improve the system as a whole. I'm just not sure this is the right way to do it.

Comment: @MatthewHaugen I appreciate your time and efforts to explain to me.

Comment: @MatthewHaugen, people like you will change SO to a better direction

Comment: @oscar Technically @Matt is doing his best to *avoid* unnecessary changes! Next time you propose something, think about the negative effects, and how it affects everyone, not just you.`

Comment: @Tim You're right, next time I won't waste my time!